# Saving Customer Orders to the database and ensuring integrity of that order is preserved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, design-patterns, model, integrity

In my Rails app, I need to store customer orders so the shop owner can still refer to the orders at a later time.

I'm concerned that after an order has been finalised, that some time later the store staff may need to change the price or details or the product going forward.

Assuming the Product is linked to the Order just by a `product_id`, this would compromise the integrity of the finalised order.

**What are the common approaches to manage this?**

An option I can think of is to, behind the scenes, not allow updates to products. If the staff perform an "update", behind the scenes the old record is just flagged as being "old" and a new Product is created in it's place.

Another option may be to store a hash in the Order model for the product as it appeared on the date of the transaction taking place.

What are the pros and cons to this? Are there other possibilities I should consider as a design recognised pattern to deal with this?

Comment: dont you think relationship between product and orders should be many-to-many as one product can be in multiple orders and orders have multiple product. If you go with many to many approach then you can save price of each product w.r.t order in joining table

Comment: @Abk thanks. You make a good point... I overlooked that detail when putting the question together. I've updated the commentary question, but I don't think it changes what I'm asking, except that it does open the possibility of saving data in the linking table. That said, it's not just price data I want to ensure is preserved, it's potentially anything. They need to see what the product "looked like" back when the transaction took place, no matter what changed since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most common approaches are to

- store all the values as they were at the time the order was placed, and
- store the history of changes to the values, so they can be recreated based on the date of the order.

So the table of line items for an order might look like this if you were storing all the values. (Date of the order wouldn't be in this table.) You might also need to store calculated values like extended price (quantity * unit_price), sales tax, etc.

```
order_num  quantity  units  product_code   product_name  unit_price
--
10132      5         each   13376-A        Widgets       $ 1.99
10132      2         dozen  BR549          Fimbels       $24.99
10132      3         boxes  THRUM          Thrums        $ 8.99
```

If you store calculated values, use validations to make sure they stay in sync with the base values.

If you were storing history, the product table might look like this. (Price changed once; name changed once.)

```
product_code  product_name  unit_price  units  from_date    to_date
--
13376-A       Widgets       $1.99       each   2014-01-01   (NULL or END_OF_TIME)
13376-A       Widgets       $1.95       each   2012-02-13   2014-12-31
13376-A       Wid-gets      $1.95       each   2009-06-17   2012-02-12
...
```

A table of line items would store the product code. The date would be in the table of orders. A join based on line_items.product_code and orders.order_date would fetch the right details from that history table. END_OF_TIME is the largest date value your dbms supports.

In either case, you need to think hard about when and how to allow updates to the tables. (Because, when you print order 10132 today, it must be the same as it printed when they placed the order.)

In many cases, systems permit *no* changes to line items. Instead, they use compensating line items. If someone ordered 5 dozen fimbels, and they meant to order 6 dozen, the system wouldn't allow you to change 5 to 6. Instead, it would just add another line item for 1 dozen fimbels. (Or it would *appear* to let you change 5 to 6, but instead store a compensating line item.)